# Notification Icon

Tags: notification-icons

I am puzzled by a notification icon in the status bar and I was hoping someone could help me. It's similar to the WiFi icon but is in a white square. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: What do you see when you pull down the notification bar? Looks like a available WiFi-connection to me or a hotspot symbol. Do you have a hotspot enabled?

Comment: What is your device model and Android version?

Answer (score 0):

It is indicating that your device's **Personal hotspot** is turned on.